# Time Series Classification for loan data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, predictive-modeling, prediction

I have multiple columns for loan installment repayment. As there is a field for month of repayment, I want to predict if the customer is going to pay next month's installment or not.

As I have multiple variables and target variable as installment paid (Y/N), despite repayment being dependent on time variable, i.e., installments paid in past months, I'm looking to solve this problem with time series classification.

Any references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in ***multivariate time series forecasting***. Below are some references to an example that sounds similar -- using multiple input variables to forecast air quality.

- [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dsg-hackathon/overview)- see *Discussion* tab for some nice examples and, well, discussion.
- [Corresponding tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-machine-learning-models-for-multivariate-multi-step-air-pollution-time-series-forecasting/)